# how to find the groups of same number and color gives the different color in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

i would like to give a different color for same same number group.

suppose i have matrix of an image.

```
I = [0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
```

here i have 1s group for 2 time and i would like to give two different color for each group. but i am not able to make them as two group. i can just give a single color for both group.

```
sz=size(I);
color=(1,3)

    red(I == 1) = color(1, 1);
    green(I == 1) = color(1, 2);
    blue(I == 1) = color(1, 3);
    for i = 1:sz(1)
        for j = 1:sz(2)            
            if L(i, j) == 1
                red(i, j) = color(1, 1);
                green(i, j) = color(1, 2);
                blue(i, j) = color(1, 3);
            end
        end
    end
end
im = cat(3, red, green, blue);
figure, imshow(im)
```

please help me...............

Comment: so do you mean, you want to give different colors to following patterns: `[0,0,...,1,0,...0]` and `[0,0,...,1,1,...0]` and `[0,0,...,1,1,1,0,...0]`?

Comment: Dear Parag i want only 1's value. as i have 2 groups for 1 value.

Comment: oh you meant like that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `bwlabel` on your matrix to do that.

```
A=bwlabel(I)
```